# Creating multipule tiers to a filter - sorting.js

Tags: javascript, sorting, filtering

So with a typical JS filtering, you can set up categories A B C D and sort a gallery that way.

I'm looking to be able to add another tier.

So you have a gallery with 12 blocks. Some will link to a photo, some to a video. They are all of dogs cats and birds.

I would like to be able to have 1st level filter between photos or videos.
Then the next layer of filtering would be to further define - dogs cats or birds.

All - Photos - Videos 
All - Dogs - Cats - Birds

I have the typical 1 level filtering set up here:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('ul#filter a').click(function () {
        $(this).css('outline', 'none');
        $('ul#filter .current').removeClass('current');
        $(this).parent().addClass('current');

        var filterVal = $(this).text().toLowerCase().replace(' ', '-');

        if (filterVal == 'all') {
            $('ul#portfolio li.hidden').fadeIn('slow').removeClass('hidden');
        } else {

            $('ul#portfolio li').each(function () {
                if (!$(this).hasClass(filterVal)) {
                    $(this).fadeOut('normal').addClass('hidden');
                } else {
                    $(this).fadeIn('slow').removeClass('hidden');
                }
            });
        }

        return false;
    });
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bmcwebdev/xFVBE/)

Comment: When you say sorting, you mean filter?

Comment: I do, let me change that.

Comment: sorry, where in your post is the actual question that you would like us to help you answer?